# SQL Summing Group in a Group

Tags: sql, join, web-sql

I have two tables in a webSQL based Chrome extension:

The first table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID int, X int, Y int, tID int, vID int, Village varchar(50), 
uID int, Player varchar(50), aID int, Alliance varchar(20), Population int)
```

The second table:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (ID int, Region varchar(20))
```

Each entry in the first table is a village. The values of ID are unique and correspond to the same village, so each village also has a region, but these tables cannot (easily) be created as one table so I've gotten as far as using:

```
FROM (table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID)
```

I want to get the sum of each alliance in each region, so the result looks something like:

```
Region      Alliance Name   Total Population/Region

REGION_A    Alliance_1      SUM(Alliance_1) in REGION_A
REGION_B    Alliance_1      SUM(Alliance_1) in REGION_B
REGION_B    Alliance_2      SUM(Alliance_2) in REGION_B
```

...and so on.

Comment: So what stops you?

Comment: My knowledge of SQL... will add one of the things I tried which was close but not quite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select b.region, a.alliance, sum(a.population) from
table1 a join table2 b on a.aid=b.id group by b.region, a.alliance;
```

Comment: So simple, didn't know it was possible to group by multiple things